# How to do mutual exclusion with two groups of functions?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, synchronization

I'm not asking directly about mutexes, although somehow related.

There are 2 groups of functions A and B. When a function in A is running, none of the functions in B should run, and vice versa.

There are multiple threads that can call functions in A or B, and the above should be satisfied.

I can think of many ways to do this by mixing some ways of locking, but I'm confused about what is the best way to do this, or at least some good ways to narrow down.

Comment: Which language are you using — C or C++?  Which version of that language are you using?  Which platform or platforms are you working on?  Are you looking for code using facilities provided by the language standard, or are you looking at facilities provided by the host O/S?  And, generically, why do you think a mutex is not appropriate?  One mutex could be used to protect both set A and set B functions; you must grab that mutex before calling any of the routines in either set.  Of course, that reduces concurrency, but that seems to be acceptable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have full access to posix threads. I'm trying to find a way to minimize locking.

Comment: Just to be clear - there can be 200 threads calling a function in group A, as long as no thread  is in a function in group B, yes?

Comment: ^^ OK, I realised my comment was unclear:)

Comment: If you have 200 threads currently using functions from group A, how does a thread that needs access to the functions in group B stop new threads calling functions in group A so that it is not starved of access.  And conversely, of course.  What rules do you want to impose?  I can see that a simple mutex is not appropriate but I'm not sure what is.

Comment: ^^ I think this is gonna be one of those messy things with a state-machine inside a lock.  Threads that are not permitted to run are held on an event/semaphore after releasing the lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so there are three valid states:

No threads are running functions in either group.

One or more threads are running functions in group A.

One or more threads are runnning functions in group B.

Like most complex locking schemes, this can be managed by state inside a lock.  The state could be an enum, eg (EgsFree, EgsAonly, EgsBonly), a threadCount int that keeps track of how many threads of either group are in the protected functions and a container for synchro objects upon which threads that were not allowed to run are waiting.

The functions would need to cooperate by calling into the locked state on entry, (identifying their group with a parameter), and on exit.

Threads that find out on attempted entry that they are not allowed to run their function must block themselves by raising an event/semaphore, storing it in the container and waiting on it after exiting the locked state.  This allows threads that decrement the count to 0, (and so set the state to Efree again), on exit to iterate the container and make all the waiting threads ready.

Given this framework, you can implement an anti-starvation algorithm, or other management schemes, as you wish.

State data in a lock is messy and I would like to see a simpler solution to this problem.  OTOH, it remains the only safe way of complex resource-management that I know of that can be relied upon to work and have no hidden race/deadlock potential.  If you have to think too hard about a locking scheme, the chances are that it will screw up at some point:)

Comment: Yup, the anti-starvation algorithm will be key, and an ongoing implementation nightmare. Which is to say that OP can't possibly avoid thinking too hard about this. Hence, I conclude that although I have no idea what the OP is doing, s/he's almost certainly doing it wrong.

Comment: ^ I didn't suggest it was a good requirement, just that it could be met;)  I understand that, if one thread calls a group functiion that loops or blocks in its body, that's the end for all the threads that try an call functions in the other group:(

Comment: Agreed, which is why I upvoted. Plastic bags are useful too, but they always come with a warning, "Danger of suffocation". I figured this answer needed a similar warning, "Danger of insanity" :)

Comment: Well, the OP requirement is a little unhinged, my answer is merely the padded cell.

Comment: @user3386109 Why do you think I'm doing sth wrong? For example, you have a copying memory manager, and you certainly don't want object access and object moving happen at the same time. Those two group of actions should be separated strictly when there are multiple threads.

Comment: @xiver77: what you describe now is normally solved by a [multiple read single write lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)

Comment: @xiver77 See [what-is-the-XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). stefaanv's quick answer to your hypothetical problem-X is a perfect example.

Comment: @user3386109 So what? I got a perfect solution to my problem and also a basic grasp on how rwlocks may be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

**I was writing this code before I saw the answer from Martin James.  It turns out to be untested c++11 code that illustrates his answer, so please upvote that answer.**

I think a three way switch with reference counting may work (Not tested class)

```
struct ThreeWaySwitch
{
  std::mutex mtx;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  enum State { IDLE, A, B } state;
  int count;

  ThreeWaySwitch() : state(IDLE), count(0) {}
  void switchA() 
  { 
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mtx); 
    while (state == B) cv.wait(l); 
    state = A; 
    ++count; 
  }
  void switchB() 
  { 
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mtx); 
    while (state == A) cv.wait(l); 
    state = B; 
    ++count; 
  }
  void switchIdle() 
  { 
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mtx); 
      if (count == 0) return;  // already idle
      if (--count != 0) return; // not idle yet
      state = IDLE;
    }
    cv.notify_all(); 
  }
};
```

So each A function calls switchA() on entry and switchIdle() on exit and switchB() for B functions.

Comment: Hmm.. Us geneusses must wrok toogethr:)

Comment: @MartinJames: thanks, I can put the code in your answer and remove mine if that's okay with you.  Your description was remarkable similar to what I had in mind.

Comment: TBH, such a design is just about the only solution that stands a chance of working reliably with a complex locking requirment.   Any time I see more than one lock I get ~~jittery~~

Comment: Good catch, I moved the check

Comment: Yes, the three states are implicit in the sign of the counter.  One small remark: in the begin functions, the check before the while loop doesn't buy you anything: the condition is the same.

Comment: @stefaanv Ah yes I see!

Comment: Perfect answer. Minor modification: template should be specified in lock objects. e.g. `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mtx);`

Comment: @Homaei Correct and in the last case, I forgot to provide a variable name, so the lock will be released immediately.

Comment: @stefaanv Thanks for the modification. And, one more (probably unrelated) question: Do you have any idea about multi-process situations? More precisely, if process 1 calls a function in A, how can we prevent process 2 from calling B functions?

Comment: @Homaei C++ has no multiprocess locking. There are posix semaphores (https://www.softprayog.in/programming/posix-semaphores) and windows has its mechanisms (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/interprocess-synchronization). I haven't used it yet, so I'm not commenting on these.

Comment: @stefaanv Thank you. I appreciate your time. I thought about my own question for hours without getting results. I combined different mechanisms such as named semaphore, inter-process mutex, etc. The challenge seems to be more difficult than it seems at first glance!

Answer (score 0):

I try to find the more open/simple answer to your problem, and you can do that :

```
class A
{
public:
    static void foo1();
    static void foo2();
private:
    static std::shared_ptr<MyMutexClass> m_mmc;
};

class B
{
public:
    static void foo3();
    static void foo4();
private:
    static std::shared_ptr<MyMutexClass> m_mmc;
};
```

Inside your foo fonctions, put guards using the static mutex provided by the group.
You just have to find a way to initialize A::m_mmc and B::m_mmc properly.